# Problema Sobre SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, ios8, spritekit

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
una pregunta sobre spriteKit. Cada vez ejecuto un juego, me aparece el objeto como si el punto de coordenadas de la escena fuera en la mitad de la escena, ósea 0.5. Y he visto la documentación, y dice que el eje de coordenadas de una escena es 0.0, no sé qué hacer. Ayuda, soy principiante.
Basicamente es el fondo de flappy bird y su personaje(porque se encuentran sus componentes con facilidad, y no quería diseñar solo para precticar) en donde si oprimes o arrastras, el ave va a donde pulsaste.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let pajaro = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pajaro")

    var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
    var dt : TimeInterval = 0

    let pajaroPixelesPerSecond: CGFloat = 300.0
    var velocity = CGPoint.zero

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

        background.zPosition = -1
        addChild(background)

        pajaro.position = CGPoint(x: -210, y: 150)
        pajaro.xScale = 1/2
        pajaro.yScale = 1/2
        addChild(pajaro)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        sceneTouched(touchLocation: location)
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {    
        if lastUpdateTime > 0 {

            dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
        }else{

            dt = 0
        }

        lastUpdateTime = currentTime

        moveSprite(sprite: pajaro, velocity: velocity)
        checkBounds()

     }
    func moveSprite(sprite: SKSpriteNode, velocity: CGPoint){

        let amount = CGPoint(x: velocity.x * CGFloat(dt), y: velocity.y * CGFloat(dt))
        print("La cantidad que nos movemos \(amount)")

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + amount.x, y: sprite.position.y + amount.y)

    }


    func movePajaroToLocation(location: CGPoint){

        let offset = CGPoint(x: location.x - pajaro.position.x, y: location.y - pajaro.position.y)

        let offsetlenght = sqrt(Double (offset.x*offset.x + offset.y*offset.y))

        let direction = CGPoint(x: offset.x/CGFloat(offsetlenght), y: offset.y/CGFloat(offsetlenght))
        velocity = CGPoint(x: direction.x * pajaroPixelesPerSecond, y: direction.y * pajaroPixelesPerSecond)
    }


    func sceneTouched(touchLocation: CGPoint){

        movePajaroToLocation(location: touchLocation)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        sceneTouched(touchLocation: location)
    }


    func checkBounds() {

        let bottonLeft = CGPoint.zero

        if pajaro.position.x <= bottonLeft.x {

            pajaro.position.x = bottonLeft.x
            velocity.x = -velocity.x

        }
    }
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme(la ultima función es para evitar que el pájaro salga de la pantalla, pero como el punto de coordenadas de la escena está en la mitad, no pasa de la mitad el pájaro), y las demás clases están intactas.

Comment: Que es lo que tienes en 0.5?? Puedes agregar el codigo/config de la escena que tienes

Comment: Hola Ramon. No hagas preguntas duplicadas. Edita esta pregunta para mejorar la explicacion y tu problema. Y contesta a los comentarios para resolver dudas de usuarios. Mira [tour] de nuevo para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio- Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, el sistema de coordenadas de UIKit es diferente al de SpriteKit. Mientras el de UIKit empieza en la parte superior izquierda, el de SpriteKit empieza en la parte inferior izquierda.

Dicho esto, yo creo que tu problema está en que mientras en UIKit la posición de las vistas viene relacionada por la coordenada x e y la cual es 0,0 en la esquina superior izquierda de la vista (propiedad origin del frame de la vista), en SpriteKit la posición viene dada por la coordenada x e y que también es 0,0 pero está en el centro del nodo (propiedad position). te recomiendo revisar este concepto al momento de crear tus nodos en SpriteKit, estoy casi seguro de que tu problema está en una mala comprensión del sistema de coordenadas de SpriteKit.

Comment: ok, tocara seguir repasando la documentación, no puede ser que yo sea el único afectado, voy a seguir leyendo, gracias por responder.